# CSS 2 forms on the same page different ID overwritting one another

Tags: css, forms, drop-down-menu

I have a page with a log in form on the right and email request form on the left.  Each one a has a drop down that look very different from the other.  For some reason styles are over writing one another. If I change the second form it changes the style on the first, what am I doing wrong?

```
#left .home-form-left input, select{height:26px; line-height:26px; border:1px solid #999999; color:#666666; font-size:12px;}



.sq-question input, select, option{width:195px; margin-bottom:5px;}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because the second `select` is overwriting the first.

To fix this, you need to be more specific, like this

`#left .home-form-left input, #left .home-form-left select {/*styles*/}`

`.sq-question input, .sq-question select, .sq-question option {/*styles*/}`

When you just place the `select` there, without anything in front of it, you are saying *style all selects this way*

In my examples above, I directly referencing the location of each element that I want to style, separating with commas as necessary.

Comment: That makes sense, thanks Jason.  I usually define them all at once #name input, select, option;  Bad habit, with multiple forms on the page.